# How to use qualifiedByName with subclass mapping

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have the following mappers:

```
@Mapper(uses = ApiMapper.class,
        // Disable use of the builders which we mostly need for testing.
        builder = @Builder(disableBuilder = true))
public interface CsgoDetailsApiMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "title", source = "match.title")
    @Mapping(target = "status", source = "match.state")
    @Mapping(target = "teams", source = "match.teams")
    @Mapping(target = "games", source = "gameDetails")
    @Mapping(target = "id", source = "match.id")
    @Mapping(target = "facts", source = "matchDetails")
    Match toApi(CsgoMatchDetails matchDetails);

    @Named("toMatchApiMissing")
    @Mapping(target = "title", source = "match.title")
    @Mapping(target = "status", source = "match.state")
    @Mapping(target = "teams", source = "match.teams")
    @Mapping(target = "games", source = "gameDetails", qualifiedByName = "toGameApiMissing")
    @Mapping(target = "id", source = "match.id")
    @Mapping(target = "facts", source = "matchDetails")
    Match toMatchApiMissing(CsgoMatchDetails matchDetails);

    ...
}
```

Similar to this I have two more mappers looking exactly the same. `LolDetailsApiMapper` and `DotaDetailsApiMapper`

then I have a details mapper that should use the implementation of the specific mappers:

```
@Mapper(uses = {
        LolDetailsApiMapper.class,
        CsgoDetailsApiMapper.class,
        DotaDetailsApiMapper.class
})
public interface DetailsApiMapper {

    @BeanMapping(unmappedTargetPolicy = IGNORE)
    @SubclassMapping(target = Match.class, source = LolMatchDetails.class)
    @SubclassMapping(target = Match.class, source = CsgoMatchDetails.class)
    @SubclassMapping(target = Match.class, source = DotaMatchDetails.class)
    Match toApi(MatchDetails matchDetails);

    @BeanMapping(unmappedTargetPolicy = IGNORE)
    @SubclassMapping(target = Match.class, source = LolMatchDetails.class)
    @SubclassMapping(target = Match.class, source = CsgoMatchDetails.class)
    @SubclassMapping(target = Match.class, source = DotaMatchDetails.class)
    Match toMatchApiMissing(MatchDetails matchDetails);

}
```

How can I make the `DetailsApiMapper.toMatchApiMissing` use the `toMatchApiMissing` of the other mappers, instead of the `toApi`? I tried adding `@Named("toMatchApiMissing")` to the specific mappers and then tried to use `@BeanMapping(unmappedTargetPolicy = IGNORE, qualifiedByName="toMatchApiMissing")`, but this didn't work. Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to annotate `toApi` method in all subclass mappers with `@Named`, instead of `toMatchApiMissing` method, as shown below:

```java
@Mapper(uses = ApiMapper.class,
        // Disable use of the builders which we mostly need for testing.
        builder = @Builder(disableBuilder = true))
public interface CsgoDetailsApiMapper {

    @Named("toApi")
    @Mapping(target = "title", source = "match.title")
    @Mapping(target = "status", source = "match.state")
    @Mapping(target = "teams", source = "match.teams")
    @Mapping(target = "games", source = "gameDetails")
    @Mapping(target = "id", source = "match.id")
    @Mapping(target = "facts", source = "matchDetails")
    Match toApi(CsgoMatchDetails matchDetails);

    @Mapping(target = "title", source = "match.title")
    @Mapping(target = "status", source = "match.state")
    @Mapping(target = "teams", source = "match.teams")
    @Mapping(target = "games", source = "gameDetails", qualifiedByName = "toGameApiMissing")
    @Mapping(target = "id", source = "match.id")
    @Mapping(target = "facts", source = "matchDetails")
    Match toMatchApiMissing(CsgoMatchDetails matchDetails);
}
```

Then rebuild the project and check the generated mapper implementation. It's a weird solution, but in my case, Mapstruct picked the right methods for mapping, i.e. those not annotated with `@Named`.

EDIT:

I've found [the issue](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/3119?fbclid=IwAR1OtM0--O5Xl8a3Up1NNUjNuFxHlPvlIR0M6zolfwBW5KxexGyme1cBQtQ) related to the topic, and it appears that the upcoming `1.6.0` milestone release will enable the use of qualifiers within the `SubclassMapping` annotation.

After the release, you will be able to define a subclass mapping as follows:

```java
@SubclassMapping(target = Match.class, source = CsgoMatchDetails.class, qualifiedByName = "toMatchApiMissing")
```